# reason: '-[Detail addDetailRelationship:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000ad740

Tags: ios, core-data, entity

I'm try to insert data into an entity using one to many relationship. My entity name is `Student` and `Detail`. `Student` to `Detail` have multiple relationship and `Detail` to `student` one relationship. Relationship name is `detailRelationship` from `Student` to `Detail` & `studentRelationship` from `Detail` to `Student`.

StudentCoreDataclassProperties

```
#import "Student+CoreDataClass.h"


NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Student (CoreDataProperties)

+ (NSFetchRequest<Student *> *)fetchRequest;

@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSString *number;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<Detail *> *detailRelationship;

@end

@interface Student (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addStudentRelationshipObject:(Detail *)value;
- (void)removeStudentRelationshipObject:(Detail *)value;
- (void)addStudentRelationship:(NSSet<Detail *> *)values;
- (void)removeStudentRelationship:(NSSet<Detail *> *)values;

@end
```

DetailCoreDataclassProperties

```
#import "Detail+CoreDataClass.h"


NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Detail (CoreDataProperties)

+ (NSFetchRequest<Detail *> *)fetchRequest;

@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSString *address;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) Student *studentRelationship;
//@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<Detail *> *studentRelationship;

@end

@interface Detail (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addDetailRelationshipObject:(Detail *)value;
- (void)removeDetailRelationshipObject:(Detail *)value;
- (void)addDetailRelationship:(NSSet<Detail *> *)values;
- (void)removeDetailRelationship:(NSSet<Detail *> *)values;

@end
```

code for insert data

```
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    _mainContext = [appDelegate manageObjectContext];

    Detail *detailtEntity = (Detail *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Detail" inManagedObjectContext:_mainContext];
    _studentClass = (Student *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Student" inManagedObjectContext:_mainContext];

    detailtEntity.name = _nameText.text;
    detailtEntity.address = _addressText.text;
    detailtEntity.address = _addressText1.text;
    detailtEntity.name = _nameText1.text;
    _studentClass.number = _numberText.text;
    NSMutableSet *mySet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    [mySet addObject: _studentClass];
    [detailtEntity addDetailRelationship:mySet];//crash app here
    detailtEntity.studentRelationship = _studentClass;

    NSError *error = nil;
    [_mainContext save:&error];

    if (![_mainContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"error in adding data %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

> show me error like this: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[Detail addDetailRelationship:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x6000000ad740'

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a message with signature

```
- (void)addDetailRelationship:(NSSet<Student *> *)values,
```

but no method with that signature exists. Instead your signature is

```
- (void)addDetailRelationship:(NSSet<Detail *> *)values
```

(notice the change from `Detail *` to `Student *`. Thus, your app will crash with an unrecognized selector exception. I don't know what the logic of you program is, but you need to either create a method with this signature or pass in parameters of the correct type.

Comment: i am try to learn multiple entity and in this code try to insert detail Entity in two record and student entity in link only number of that two record available in Detail. now you understand what's M do? Thanks.

Comment: Hey after changes show me error like this: reason: '-[Detail addDetailRelationship:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000ad7a0'

Answer (score 0):

Core data manages relationship inverses for you. If you set the detail's student relationship core data will automatically set it as one of students' details. There is no need at all for the that is crashing, so just remove

```
    [detailtEntity addDetailRelationship:mySet];//crash app here
```

(The reason it is crashing is that you need to addDetailRelationship on the student -     [_studentClass addDetailRelationship:mySet]. But as I said above you don't need the line at all)